# How can I wrap characters in stringA with a tag if they are found in stringB?

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, preg-replace

For example:

```
$stringA = 'Whatcha talkin bout Willis?';
$stringB = 'aeiou';
```

I need to wrap all characters in stringB matching any in stringA with a `<span>`.

How can I do this?

```
echo tagVowels($stringA);

function tagVowels($string) {
    // ????
    // So far I've been using a manual loop through each character.
    // I'm hoping for a simpler/cleaner way.
    for ($i = 0; $i <= strlen($string) -1; $i++) {
        if (strpos()) {
            $string = str_replace();
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Wh<span>a</span>tch<span>a</span> t<span>a</span>lk<span>i</span>n bout W<span>i</span>ll<span>i</span>s
```

Comment: What have you tried? What about `ou` in `bout`? Should they be wrapped together or in individual spans?

Comment: I've been doing a highly manual loop through each character of the string.  Something like this: `for ($i = 0; $i <= strlen($string) -1; $i++) { }`  I'm hoping for a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a character class from `$stringB`:

```
$stringA = preg_replace('/['.$stringB.']/', '<span>$0</span>', $stringA);
```

This will wrap every single of those characters in `span` tags. If you want consecutive matching characters to end up in the same span tag, use this:

```
$stringA = preg_replace('/['.$stringB.']+/', '<span>$0</span>', $stringA);
```

Note that this approach will get ugly, if you include characters that are meta-characters within regex character classes (`^]-\`). However, as Brad Christie mentioned you can get around this problem, if you call `preg_quote($stringB)` instead of inserting `$stringB` right away.

Comment: As an aside, you can [`preg_quote`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) `$stringB` before placing it within the pattern.

Comment: @BradChristie I thought about that, but I was not aware that it will escape `-` as well, since it is usually not a special character. Also it will of course escape way too many characters, but that should not be a problem. I'll add it, thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 1):

Using a non-regex variation, take advantage of `str_replace`'s ability to accept arrays:

```
$find = str_split($stringB);
$replace = array();
foreach ($find as $ltr)
{
    $replace[] = sprintf('<span>%s</span>', $ltr);
}
$stringA = str_replace($find, $replace, $stringA);
```

Simple example: http://ideone.com/3CKctq